# Assigning a dictionary to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assign a dictionary object to a cell in a `pandas` data frame. In order to prevent the incompatible indexing error, I wrapped the dictionaries in a list, which caused some cells to contain a list and some a dictionary! The way I did is:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.at['r1','c1']=[{'e1':1, 'e2':2}]
df.at['r2','c2']=[{'e1':1, 'e2':2}]
df.at['r1','c2']=[{'e1':1, 'e2':2}]
df.at['r2','c1']=[{'e1':1, 'e2':2}]
```

The result is:

```py
             c1                    c2
r1    {'e1': 1, 'e2': 2}  [{'e1': 1, 'e2': 2}]
r2  [{'e1': 1, 'e2': 2}]    {'e1': 1, 'e2': 2}
```

I am wondering why this happens and if there are any solutions.

Please note that this is a toy example to demonstrate the problem I have. In the real problem, the DF is much larger and its values are assigned dynamically as they are provided to it.